# Python Test Code inside VI

Tags: python, linux, shell, vi

Sometimes I need to test my python code in shell, so I have to edit the code, save and quit and run the code. Then reopen the file to modify my code if anything goes wrong. Then save and quit .... I am wondering is there a handy feature in VI to easily test the code inside VI?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the issue, but what about running the python from the command line via `:!python %`? What do you mean by 'test', just running the code?

Comment: http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide#test-integration

Comment: Try iPython. It's an interactive shell for python.

Comment: What about using two sessions at the same time? So when you save in one, you test in the other.

Comment: @TankorSmash, I mean just run the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but if you have Ipython, it has a handy bit of magic called %autoreload.

For example: test.py

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
     self.a = 0
```

Then I run ipython -i test.py

```
In [2]: a=A()

In [3]: a.a
Out[3]: 0
```

Ooops, the initial 'a' value should be 21... I better fix that.

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
     self.a = 21
```

Now in ipython I do, again this is in the SAME INSTANCE OF IPYTHON:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload
```

This will reload the class A object into python for me, so now.

```
In [4]: a.a
Out[4]: 21
```

This can really help when debugging a large class, and are only making small changes.
My workflow typically consists of having two terminal windows open, one with vim for editing the .py files, and one running ipython to test and debug the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I do this all the time.
In your vimrc put:

```
command R ! python ./%
```

Then :R will execute the python code. I also have this for debug though it's not as useful as I would have liked:

```
command D ! python -m ipdb ./%
```

It runs it in debug, but our environment typically doesn't dig on the perpetual rerun in the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

I might be interpreting your questions incorrectly but this is my suggestion. Maybe you can open more than one terminal. On one terminal, write/edit your code and save it. I'm assuming with ':w' and leave the terminal open. Then on the other terminal, compile your code.